# Cannot show camera permission alert again when triggering AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess again

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, uitest, camerapermission

I try to reset the camera permission by inject a `.notDetermined` value to AVAuthorizationStatus. And I could see in below code `AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video)` is retriggered, however the camera alert is not presented again on iPhone.

My question is if `AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video)` will do recheck in some DB for the AVAuthorizationStatus, or it just pops the permission alert, in which way I should have the alert on iPhone. And where the camera permission is stored in iPhone, any persistent storage, and can we clear that storage in code?

And go through several posts already, they advice to uninstall the app, but in automation UI test, we cannot uninstall an app from what I know.

```
    private var isAuthorized: Bool {
        get async {
            // If UI Test, inject AVAuthorizationStatus = .notDetermined
            let status = RuntimeEnv.isUITest ? .notDetermined : AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
            
            var isAuthorized = status == .authorized
            
            if status == .notDetermined {
                isAuthorized = await AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video)
            }

            return isAuthorized
        }
    }
```

Comment: Once the permission dialog has been shown once it will not be shown again unless you delete your app and reinstall it.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I saw the same. But could we delete the DB which store the camera permission state, it must be saved in some place.

Comment: You might be able to reset the simulator or maybe find the file in the simulator where it is stored. You can't do anything on a real device

Comment: Why do you want to test a functionality which actually Apple is responsible for? If the test ever failed you can't fix it.

Comment: Hello @vadian because we have several test cases from QA, so I want to automate them with UI Test. But, yeah I think it is better to leave them for manual test only as current situation.

Comment: @ZhouHaibo There is no programmatic way of doing this. This has UX reasons that Apple wants developers to consider: Users would be massively annoyed if the app keeps asking for permissions again and again and again. Thus: once the dialog is dismissed, there is no way of bringing it back. You can however ask the user to go into the iPhone settings and change the permissions there.

Answer (score 0):

In general, once a privacy request dialog has been shown, it won't be shown again.

If you are testing on a simulator and want to reset the device state before the next test run you can use the `xcrun simctl` command in the terminal:

`xcrun simctl privacy <device> reset all <your.app.bundle>` will reset all privacy permission states for the specified simulator `<device>`.  You can omit `<your.app.bundle>` to reset permissions for all apps on the device.

There is no method to reset permission request state on a real device aside from removing and re-installing your app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use prescript in Xcode scheme to uninstall / install the app before each test run. And in this way, camera permission alert could be triggered again.

And I just found the pre-actions script only was triggered for the 1st test if perform a sequence of tests...

```
xcrun simctl uninstall booted <bundle id>
sleep 2
xcrun simctl install booted <use absolute path to your app, related path not work here>
```